# GMail - Email Sent To Multiple People (CC'd) Received At Different Times

Tags: email, gmail

Our organization sends an email to all of our employees several times a month. Sometimes, we'll have accounting send time-sensitive emails to particular contacts, but all CC'd. Why would someone who is also on gsuite, but a different gsuite account, receive the email at 12:00PM and someone else might receive it at 5:00PM? All users either on the same organizational gsuite account, or another organizational gsuite account.

Comment: It is a really broad question. At least you should add the message header to the Message received delayed by the recipient. To get the message header  follow this article Trace an email with its full headers: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en

Comment: Then edit your answer and add the message header. Alos add the mesage header of the message sent